# Where did the 70 elders (High Sanhedrin) sit in the wilderness?

Tags: dor-hamidbar, sanhedrin

All the depictions of the tribal camps around the Mishkan in the desert show that the tribe of Levi was surrounding it and Israel were not allowed in there.

I don't recall a reference to a specific place of the elders, instead, they were following Moses here and there

So where did the 70 elders sit in the desert?

Comment: Since they had to go to the mishkan, Bnai Yisrael could normally enter the machane leviyah. The elders probably met at the tent of Moshe. Those who were not allowed in the camp involved *tum'ah* (ritual impurity) of the various types